# add quarter months to expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I need to add to this expression.

```
=IIF(cstr(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) IS Nothing," ",Fields!Netincome.Value)
```

This currently hides data if the field MainIndicator Value is NULL.

I want to however show the data if months are March, June, Sep, Dec

Can anyone advise?

Comment: I have tried this. IIF(cstr(Fields!MainIndicatorValue) IS Nothing or Str(month(Fields!date.value)) ="March" ,Fields!Netincome.Value, " ") to start off with. But not quite working

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
IIF(CSTR(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = "Mar" 
OR CSTR(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = "Jun" 
OR CSTR(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = "Sep" 
OR CSTR(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = "Dec" ,Fields!Netincome.Value," ")
```

**EDIT**: 
You have added further comments which change the answer (it's not clear what you are asking for).
Try:

```
IIF(MonthName(CDATE(Fields!MainIndicator.Value)) = "March" 
OR MonthName(CDATE(Fields!MainIndicator.Value)) = "June" 
OR MonthName(CDATE(Fields!MainIndicator.Value)) = "September" 
OR MonthName(CDATE(Fields!MainIndicator.Value)) = "December" ,Fields!Netincome.Value," ")
```

Comment: thankyou @BIDeveloper. I need to include IIF(cstr(Fields!MainIndicatorValue) IS Nothing

Comment: so just add another OR condition..
Actually.... no you do not... that sample still hides data if it is nothing.

Comment: Thanks but it's coming up with blank. I need to ensure when the period is for the other months if the the MainIndicator is NULL the data is not displayed for these buildings. The date in my db is in this format 2016-03-31 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=Switch( IsNothing(Fields!MainIndicator.Value), ""
, Month(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = 3, Fields!Netincome.Value
, Month(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = 6, Fields!Netincome.Value
, Month(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = 9, Fields!Netincome.Value
, Month(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) = 12, Fields!Netincome.Value
, True, ""
)
```

Comment: Thank you @StevenWhite. It is still quite not there. May be if I try an explain a bit more clearly. Using this piece of code of yours currently still hides some of the data where the  MainIndicator is Null. I am running the report for March so all the data should show. If however I was to run the report for Feb then those buildings with Mainindicator of Null should be hidden.

Comment: Just a small test to start off with.....Then I will add the remaining months if it works however I have tried this and it gives my  #Error                                                   =switch( Month(Parameters!Report_Month.Value) = 3 and cstr(Fields!MainIndicator.Value) IS Nothing, true, Fields! Netincome.Value)

Comment: @Camille the `Switch` statement can't take 3 arguments. Looks like you were thinking of an `IIf` statement.

Comment: I have tried to simplify right down. Please could someone help correct formula. 'What I am trying to acheive...in this order.... If the MainIndicator is Null, display blank
else if the MainIndicator is NULL then display 0
else display the Netincome value

'
=switch(IsNothing(Fields!MainIndicator.Value), " ", 
isnothing(Fields!Netincome.Value), "-", 
Fields!Netincome.value)
'

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this. I was missing the true part `=switch(IsNothing(Fields!MainIndicator.Value), " ", isnothing(Fields!Netincome.Value), "-", true Fields!Netincome.value)`